# How to create a POST listener

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a method to listen to post requests on my site. The payment gateway needs this url, but i don't know how to make this.

Comment: explain what you having problem????

Comment: I have no idea how to start. Maybe using just a method with [HttpPost] and the parameters that i want to receive... but what about the amount of requests? If I receive a lot of requests my website can break?

Comment: @fvss The number of requests your site can handle has more to do with hardware and performance of the underlying software than design of your MVC actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`HttpPostAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(...)
{
   ...
}
```